# Diff by developer in one file

Tags: bash, mercurial

How I can get ONLY changes maked by one developer? I mean, get the diff between two revisions to all files changed by one developer, and only these changes, not others. The following command get files modified by developer between to dates, but I want diff of these file between two change set

```
hg log -k $dev -d "$start to $end" --template "{file_mods}{file_adds}\n"
```

If I try:

```
hg diff -r -1:<rev> $file
```

I get diff for all developers, not for one.

Comment: You want to see the diff between two arbitrary revisions that only a single developer made? What about if they changed something that someone else changed first? What about if someone changed something again after they changed it? Also do you want individual changes or cumulative changes (what if they change something more than once)?

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I am looking for:

```
hg log -p -u <name> -r <rev1>:<rev2>
```

Is for all files in changeset, but with this method I have not to go over all files previously calculated. For one developer, -u is your friend.